# How to fetch foreach activity output to until activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm new to work with data factory. I want to know how can I fetch ForEach activity's inner activity result from outer Until activity. I have my pipeline as below.

[image]

**My ForEach1 activity looks like this,**
[image]

**My until activity looks like this.**
[image]

I want to fetch Azure Function activity's output from Web activity, but pipeline is failing with the error **"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=cannot reference action 'Log_extraction_func_copy1'. The action 'Log_extraction_func_copy1' is nested in a foreach scope of multiple levels. Referencing repetition actions from outside the scope is supported only when there are no multiple levels of nesting"**. Is there any way out for this? Sorry, I'm not good at English.Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the output of function in a variable using set variable and access the variable value from web activity.